# I upgraded to a new My Monero App now I lost my coins?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, security, mnemonic-seed, viewkey

I download the update 0.17.0.1-afc2e84(QT 5.9.9) and now it's taken me back to the original options (language, mode selection, open a wallet etc. Where do I find my old wallet key on my PC? I don't remember any of the mnemonic words and don't believe I have them written down. I have my username, password, phone etc. will this help? Thanks

Comment: I managed to find my 25 mnemonic words but my balance which was just above 1 XMR is now back down to zero?

Comment: Is the daemon AND the wallet fully sync'd?  Might take a while for it to fully catch up after doing a wallet restore with the 25 magic words.

Comment: @WS455 for future reference, you can update your original question (when it changes from what you originally asked) by clicking the 'edit' button. Answers are meant for actual answers, not updates to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need your mnemonic seed. Since you've found it, what is your restore height? You might need to lower it a bit, it depends when was the last transaction.